# Android/Java :How to save a timer to a database and compare it with others

Tags: java, android, timer

I have  just started creating a project for my college and i need to make an android app. The idea is that the user will read a story to others and they have to find whats the right answer. Also at the same time when the user hits the story that he wants a timer shows up and counts the time passing. When the answer is correct the timer will stop and depending on it a message will pop up and will tell him whats his possition on the ladder. So i would like to know how its possible to save that time, store it in a database and compare it with the rest of them. I have to inform u that i have just started learning java but i have some previous experience with c and c++.  I would like to thank all of u in advance and it will be very usefull if u can guide me to the right direction.

Comment: Im not certain how to answer this, because it seems that you are asking for a solution for a whole process rather than a single point that fails.
I'd recommend reading the Android Tutorials for Developers. Those should help.

Comment: I assume that u are right. I am reading at the moment the head first java 2nd edditon and its pretty clear and the next one is the big nerd ranch guide. So i suppose i will try to repeat my question with a more specific point to the subject. I was just wondering how to save the timers.I already have found how to create a countup timer but what i do after? i create a database with mysql and connect with java?
Thanks  for ur response and i apologize for asking before learning the basics. Its just that i have 1 month to finish it and even a good guideline could be much of a use.Thanks again!

Comment: sql, yes. but sqlite. Check https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html From my understanding this is a complete tutorial on how to create and put data into the database. the developer.android.com page is a great way to start and will explain everything you need to know.